What does hostname mean in the definition of the DISPLAY enviroemnt variable
The DISPLAY environment variable is of the format
hostname:D.S.  What are the acceptable values for hostname?

You can get the value of the DISPLAY environment variable in your terminal using the following command:
printenv | grep DISPLAY

Mine returned DISPLAY=:0, while others obtained DISPLAY=:0.0. Xorg works just fine with these values to operate i3.
You see that the hostname isn't always necessarily part of the DISPLAY environment variable. Unless more context is given, I suppose you can name it anything your like. (It is suggested that you comply with the RFC1178 hostname convention.)

I am implementing a x client protocol library.  And X relies on the interpretation of the environment variable.  I guess I can look at the source of xcb or xlib to determine how they interpret it.
